# Alexa brightness automated tests issue

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-smart-home-skill

I'm developing a smart home skill for Alexa, which involves controlling a light with various capabilities such as brightness, color temperature (CT), and more. I've successfully addressed all the other issues, including CT, colors, and ON/OFF functionality. However, I'm encountering difficulties passing the automated tests specifically related to the brightness capabilities.

My problem is on brightness when running [automated tests](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/test-automated.html), I am getting error on brighness that is detailed bellow;

Scenario 1:
Let's assume that the initial state before the request is that the brightness is set at a value of 75.

In the first scenario, I'm retaining the brightness value it had before the "SetBrightness" command to set it to 0, which also serves as a signal to turn off the light.

Request:

```
{
   "directive":{
      "header":{
         "namespace":"Alexa.BrightnessController",
         "name":"SetBrightness",
         "messageId":"fed54fb1-a40e-42c5-819d-53894fb19fd8",
         "correlationToken":"ctooken",
         "payloadVersion":"3",
         "endpoint":{
            "scope":{
               "type":"BearerToken",
               "token":"token",
               "endpointId":"b38d964c-0b55-4b9a-8c0c-c537721bd2e5",
               "cookie":{},
               "payload":{
                  "brightness":0
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "event":{
      "header":{
         "namespace":"Alexa",
         "name":"Response",
         "messageId":"fed54fb1-a40e-42c5-819d-53894fb19fd8-R",
         "correlationToken":"ctoken",
         "payloadVersion":"",
         "endpoint":{
            "endpointId":"b38d964c-0b55-4b9a-8c0c-c537721bd2e5",
            "scope":{
               "token":"token",
               "type":"BearerToken"
            },
            "payload":{},
            "context":{
               "properties":[
                  {
                     "namespace":"Alexa.BrightnessController",
                     "value":75,
                     "name":"brightness",
                     "timeOfSample":"2023-09-08T05:30:10.410Z",
                     "uncertaintyInMilliseconds":3000
                  },
                  {
                     "namespace":"Alexa.PowerController",
                     "value":"OFF,
                     "name":"powerState",
                     "timeOfSample":"2023-09-08T05:30:10.410Z",
                     "uncertaintyInMilliseconds":3000
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When running tests, I am getting on from on https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console

Error:

```
"The endpoint could not be set to the Initial States required by the Test Case."
```

Scenario 2:
Assuming the initial brightness is set at 100.

In the second scenario, I'm setting the brightness to the value specified in the "SetBrightness" command. If the command instructs the brightness to be set to 0, I will report back a brightness value of zero along with turning off the light.

Request:

```
{
  "directive": {
    "header": {
      "namespace": "Alexa.BrightnessController",
      "name": "SetBrightness",
      "messageId": "fed54fb2-a40e-42c5-819d-53894fb19fd8",
      "correlationToken": "ctooken",
      "payloadVersion": "3",
      "endpoint": {
        "scope": {
          "type": "BearerToken",
          "token": "token-",
          "endpointId": "b38d964c-0b55-4b9a-8c0c-c537721bd2e5",
          "cookie": {},
          "payload": {
            "brightness": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "event": {
    "header": {
      "namespace": "Alexa",
      "name": "Response",
      "messageId": "fed54fb1-a40e-42c5-819d-53894fb19fd8-R",
      "correlationToken": "ctoken",
      "payloadVersion": "3",
      "endpoint": {
        "endpointId": "b38d964c-0b55-4b9a-8c0c-c537721bd2e5",
        "scope": {
          "token": "token",
          "type": "BearerToken"
        },
        "payload": {},
        "context": {
          "properties": [
            {
              "namespace": "Alexa.BrightnessController",
              "value": 0,
              "name": "brightness",
              "timeOfSample": "2023-09-08T05:30:10.410Z",
              "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 3000
            },
            {
              "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
              "value": "OFF",
              "name": "powerState",
              "timeOfSample": "2023-09-08T05:30:10.410Z",
              "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 3000
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error in EvaluationResults:

```
{
            "name": "DevRe_9.1",
            "status": "FAILED",
            "expectedCapabilityStates": [
                {
                    "namespace": "Alexa.BrightnessController",
                    "name": "brightness",
                    "value": 100
                }
            ],
            "directive": {
                "header": {
                    "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
                    "name": "TurnOn"
                },
                "payload": {}
            },
            "actualCapabilityStates": [
                {
                    "namespace": "Alexa.BrightnessController",
                    "name": "brightness",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
},
```

In the above EvaluationResults, It looks to me that it wanted the 100 back which was the value before issue setBrightness=0.

The question here is what is the expected response, when set brightness to (0)zero, is issued?
Later what is expected values When the `ReportState` is issued?

Comment: For the 1st scenario, I'd like to make sure you sent brightness=75, when you receive SetBrightness=0 or you sent birightness=0 and sent 75?

Comment: @Amari, I send brightness=75 when I receive SetBrightness=0 of course 75 being the value it poses at the time of receiving SetBrightness=0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Scenario 1: Your skill simply needs to set value=0 and send back to Alexa with value=0. SetBrightness is a request from Alexa(a user) to set your device value to specific value.
For Scenario 2: It seems that the test expects that the device returns value=100 when the device is turned on. However if the device is asked state report during the the device is off(value=0), the device should respond with current state(value=0).

Comment: It worked! Thanks, @Amari.

Comment: I have same issue but i can't understand the logic can you please explain again. Do i need to stateChange like brightness value 0 so set to powerController OFF and brightness value is 100 so set value ON Right ?

Comment: @sedhal brightness and powerState are from different interfaces. For stateReport, you simply need to send the interfaces' current state. If you receive directive to update your device state, you need to update your device state and respond back to Alexa. The test also will send initial request to set initial values so that testing device can be set expected values for interfaces. Please make sure if your skill responds and updates your device state from each request from Alexa. I'd recommend checking Alexa request and your response step by step if there is no difference between them.